# NHibernate MySQL Mapping Set Column Type

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, set

In my MySQL database, I have the following column type.

```
Field        |    Type                                        |  Null |
----------------------------------
Column_priv  |  set('Select','Insert','Update','References')  |   No  |
```

And I cannot figure out what to map this to.

Can anyone tell me how I can map this to something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a string property, if the need be have a custom class represnting each value inside the set and each time the property nhibernate uses to set the value convert it into the custom class using its constructor for the conversion.